# Can't ListObjects through AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an empty bucket at http://tstststs.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ which has the ListObjects permission enabled for public access but when executing `aws s3 ls s3://tstststs` I get the following message: `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied`

Can anyone help me figure this out? Since I have it set to public access it can't be a credential error, can it?

Comment: Are you sure you have AWS CLI configured--correctly? Use `aws configure` if unsure.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the S3 bucket policy to something like this. Note: This will allow anyone to read any object in "yourbucketname" and nothing else like listing files, uploading, etc. Amazon has published lots of examples if you need something more specific:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
        "Sid": "PublicReadOnly",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*", 
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::yourbucketname/*"
    }]
}
```

Comment: I did that but it still gives me accessdenied... the weird thing is I can access it from a browser but not from CLI :/

Answer (score 0):

The `aws s3 ls` command actually triggers more than a ListObjects command. (For example, it might fetch the bucket region, which involves more permissions.)

If you want it to purely call ListOjects, then use `aws s3api list-objects`.